# Using Cycles renderer the reflections look good in viewport but not in in the render, why is this happening?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, reflection

Im using Cycles renderer and there is no reflection when I render the image
I ve been searching for solutions but I couldnt find any,
Im using Blender 2.83

This is how it looks in the viewport
[image]

This is how it looks when I render it
[image]

This is the material
[image]

And these are the render settings

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question and add an image that shows the issue, plus an image of the materials, plus an image of the render settings. With no information is hard to help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my object not show up?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67490/why-does-my-object-not-show-up) # cause number 12

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is not the reflections, but the fact that they are blocked by something else. It looks like you have another object on top that is not visible in the 3d viewport but is renderable.

Those three big squares that are overlaid on the ground most likely belong to such object.

In the outliner search for objects that have been disabled for view (eye icon) but have the camera icon enabled. The camera icon determines if the object renders or not.

Comment: Okay, Its true, there were some planes on top,I removed them but the problem was still there. For the past 2 hours I ve been changing and moving everything  to find where the origin of the problem was. I finally tried to use the material in another plane, and it worked! So I realized that the problem was just that for some reason the ground plane I was using wasnt rendering correctly, I ve put a new plane and now I works correctly. However, thank you very much for the help!

Comment: "For some reason" is not a good reason. There has got to be a more reasonable explanation without having to put a new plane. More information is needed to get to the bottom of this.

Comment: Then don't mark the question as solved if it didn't solve anything, We all can learn a lot more by getting to the bottom of this. I'm sure it is a simple fix as well. Try this: make a copy of the original file that has the problem. Remove objects that are not relevant to the issue until you are left with the problem only. Then share the file for others to inspect.

Comment: Okay, where can I share the file?

Comment: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ paste the link in the text of the question.

Comment: Remember to "pack" the textures you are using, Otherwise they are not saved as part of the file.

Comment: Okay, you where right, there was a hidden plane that I didnt see (different from the ones I was talking about before), I was preparing the file to share it and I found it, I erased it and now it works correctly. Im sorry for the inconvenience, and thanks for the solution

Comment: Gad to help. Now the answer makes sense. Cool image, by the way!